# Unable to get the co-ordinates of the keys in ios simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

I am working on keyboard automation on `iOS` using ios simulator in `x-code`. I need to get the x and y co-ordinates of the keys on the iOS simulator to do the automation testing. I have found this code but where it will tap the point based on the vector point.

```
window.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 25, dy: 0).tap()
```

1. How to get the co-ordinate of the each keys present in the keys (numeric and special keys are also included.)?
2. How the co-ordinate will vary based on landscape and portrait mode?
   Is there any other way to get the co-ordinates of keys other than this?
   Method like keys["a"].tap() is there which will tap the 'a' key but it is not useful for me because I need to do it for different languages.